# Displaying multiple tabs in one page on the tableau server

Tags: javascript, tableau-api

I have a Workbook on the tableau server which has 10 dashboards. Right now the dashboards are displayed as tabs as I checked that option when publishing to the server. But I want to be able to show all the 10 workbooks in one page, scrolling is fine as long as I have just one link that has all the workbooks in a single page. Is there any way of doing it either on the server itself or on another webpage using HTML/Javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An ideal flow from Datasource to Data Visualisation in Tableau is:

```
+------------+     +-----------+    +----------+    +-----+
|            |     |           |    |          |    |     |
|Data Sources+---> |Work sheets+--> |Dashboards+--> |Story|
|            |     |           |    |          |    |     |
+------------+     +-----------+    +----------+    +-----+
```

Coming back to the question:

> as I have just one link that has all the workbooks in a single page.

You just need to drag multiple `worksheets` on one `dashboard`, align and arrange them and publish the `dashboard`. Remember **not** to publish the individual worksheets - just publish the dashboard and share the link of the dashboard with public.

However, the best practice is always to drag multiple `dashboards` on a single story and then publish the story and share it's URL.

In either case, do remember to publish only the dashboard / story and not the other 10 different worksheets. There's an option to un-check before you publish.